# opencart duplicate shipping methods

Tags: duplicates, opencart

I've just duplicated the flat and free shipping methods.
I've changed everything in all the files (litteraly everything from flat to flat2 etc)
I've cleared all caches, including the modifications and vqmod cache, but I can't enable the duplicated methods.

When I echo to test when trying to activate I get:

```
Array(
[shipping_flat_cost] => 19
[shipping_flat_tax_class_id] => 0
[shipping_flat_geo_zone_id] => 6
[shipping_flat_status] => 1
[shipping_flat_sort_order] => )
```

So it still refers to flat instead of flat2.

Have I missed something? 
Thanks!

Comment: did you enabled in Admin System->Users->User Groups permissions for this new module administration?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to change the actual controller names at the top of the files? IE something along the liens of: class ControllerShippingFlat extends Controller (change to) class ControllerShippingFlat2 extends Controller ?